# How do computers *really* work? (at the most basic level)

Tags: macos, mac, cpu, touchpad, input

While learning about computers I will here about RAM and Storage and the CPU, and while these explain the architecture of a computer and how parts of a computer work together, I still don't understand the *fundamental workings* of a computer program.

Let me take an example. 
I'm on the web on a mac right now. When I push two fingers away from me on the trackpad, I understand that the trackpad is made up of a capacitive touch screen that, when your finger is placed on it, draws current and the trackpad detects that and converts it into data that explains the movement of my fingers up the screen.

However, when you have this data in binary form, or machine code, it goes through logic gates and other things to make it in scroll down on the page. But what is actually happening here? How would the computer have physical things that operate differently based on the input? What operations are carried out on the machine code that says "if data looks like 01001010 10101010... send instruction 10010010... to CPU that tells computer to scroll down". To me this step is still magic. Especially with computers now that have no moving parts it seems even more alien.

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: This is probably better for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com) and probably would be rejected there because it's a broad question that has most likely been answered countless times before.

Comment: Logic gates are literally "physical things that operate differently based on the input"...

Comment: A great introduction to this topic is "Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software", published in 1999 by Microsoft Press. It looks like prices are high right now, it may be out of print, but consider the Kindle edition. I've recommended this book to at least two people asking the same kinds of questions as you are, and they both felt the book did a great job for them.

Comment: There are pdf copies all over the internet ....

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a word to the famous Richard Feynman, a father of quantum electrodynamics, a Nobel prize winner, and also very clever man. Here is his Computer Heruistics lecture:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA

It seems he explains just exactly what you're asking about.